# JSON data size limit

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, highcharts

In HighChart I needs to plot a series of data against x and y axis. HighChart expects the data to be in json format. ie, [ [ x, y],[x, y]……[x, y] ]. Where x and y are time ( 1392345000 – Unix epoch format ) and value ( 49.322 ). So I am making an ajax call to get the data and on success I render the json returned data in highchart. In most of the time ie, if the count of data( [x,y] ) is below 87500 rows than Json returns the data from controller to view. But when the data exceeds 87500 the ajax error is called with 404, not found error. Is there any size restriction for json returned data.

## Section-1 – Controller Class

```
public JsonResult GetPlotData(Dictionary<string, List<ChartData>> dataPlot)
{

    // dataPlot = D00213 - [[13245678000,49.9],[13245345000,43.9]...[n,n]]
    // if dataPlot.Count < 87500 here throwing error and in ajax error 404 Not found
    return Json(dataPlot, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

## Section-2 – Ajax

```
 $.ajax(
    {
          url: '../Report/GetPlotData',
          data: { "fromDate": fromDate, "toDate":toDate, "item": items[i].id }, 
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          cache: false,
          success: function(chartData) {
              alert(‘success’
          },
          error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) 
          {
                    debugger;
                    ShowDialogError(xhr, 'Site Status Report');
                  }
          });
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You webserver will limit the maximum response size limit. You should refer to documentation on your web server of choice to see how best to increase that limit beyond whatever it is set to today.

The JsonResult class does have a property (maxJsonLength) you may also try changing

```
var jsonResult = Json(dataPlot, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
return jsonResult;
```

Possible configuration change

```
<configuration>
    <system.web.extensions>
        <scripting>  
             <webServices>                                                   
                 <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="1000000" />                 
             </webServices>
        </scripting>
    </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

Most importantly - you may want to reconsider your call to limit or somehow partition the responses into more manageable chunks as a default response limit is fairly large and can take a long time to return (network latency)

Generally speaking it's usually not a good idea to increase your response size limit. But that is probably the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: Thanks Pepto. Now after changing the code as above able to return the large jsondata. But as you said the response limit is large it's taking long time to run. I needs to find out a way to split the response limit.

Comment: It can be really rough to design stuff like that. Best idea I could offer is to look at a tech like SignalR, open a persistent connection and send the data with multiple calls from the server to the client, compile on the client, then send to the high chart. Other option, break date into multiple calls surrounded by when promises, when all return then compile into single collection and pass on...etc

Answer (score 1):

```
var jsonResult = Json(dataPlot, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);    
jsonResult.maxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;    
return jsonResult;
```

This is a best way to crease data limit in post.

Answer (score 0):

MaxJsonLength: This helps to get or set the maximum JSON content length that you will send. The default value for this is 2097152 characters, that is equal to 4 MB of Unicode string data. You can even increase the size based if needed, for that you will get an idea later in this article

solutions:

```
protected override JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType,Encoding contentEncoding, JsonRequestBehavior behavior)

    {

    return new JsonResult()

    {

    Data = data,

    ContentType = contentType,

    ContentEncoding = contentEncoding,

    JsonRequestBehavior = behavior,

    MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue

    };

    }
```