# Angular 45000 + results

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am using Angular with ASP.NET MVC.  I have a method in my MVC Controller that returns, 45,557 records.  The method returns the record, but it never returns them to my Angular Controller. Using filters the same method returns 20,000 records, but when a user clicks "ALL" to return the entire recordset (45,557 records), the success object never gets hit.  I'm assuming this means there is a limit to the size of the result set.  If so, does anyone know what it is?  If not, what is the problem here?

Here is my Angular controller code:

```
$scope.waitsearch = generalsearchService.submitSearch($scope.form)
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.gridOptions.data = data.SearchResults;
        });
```

the ".success" object never comes back with the full recordset.  If the recordset is a subset it hits it.

The MVC Controller code:

```
                var results = await SearchClient.PostGeneralSearch(strSqlQuery, 50000, 1);
            return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

in the above code, strSqlQuery is a dynamic SQL query string, 50000 is the maximum number of records to return and 1 is the "page" number as the stored procedure in the api is set up to get 50000 records at a time.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 45,557 records to user ? Huh ! oops ! I hope you are not having 45,557  watches!

Comment: In case that JSON exceeds max allowed size, take a look at that link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451217/json-data-size-limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer at this question [Size Limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451217/json-data-size-limit) suggested by Alex Art solved my issue.  Hope this helps someone else.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Size of the data returned is too bigger for angular to handle. How many properties your object has? It can extend the size of the JSON too. I would not be in such situation simply because it is not a good UX to load all 45.5k records in single shot. Bring your payload to manageable 20k etc.

Some approaches are,

1. Use infinite scrolling and use batch of 2K records. So this loads all data as user scrolls through and well with in manageable in
   angular.
2. Load data from angular using a batched approach.