# Json can't load large number of data

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc

My C# code:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public virtual JsonResult GetBrickByBrickId(int brickId)
        {
            var brick = brickAdminRepository.GetBrickByBrickId(brickId);
            var data = new
            {
                BrickId = brick.BrickId,
                TypeId = brick.TypeId,
                Color = brick.Color,
                Name = brick.Name,
                NameBen = brick.NameBen,
                Height = brick.Height,
                Width = brick.Width,
                Length = brick.Length,
                Price = brick.Price,
                Description = brick.Description,
                DescriptionBen = brick.DescriptionBen,
                CoverImageName = brick.CoverImageName,
                CB = brick.CB,
                MB = brick.MB,
                CD = brick.CD,
                MD = brick.MD,
                IsPublished = brick.IsPublished
            };
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

My JS code:

```
 function OnLocationModify(brickId)
{
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetBrickByBrickId", "BrickAdmin")';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'get',
        async:false,
        data:
            {
                brickId: brickId,
            },
        success:function(data)
        {
            AllClear();
            if(data!=null)
            {
                $('#BrickId').val(data.BrickId);
                $('#TypeId').val(data.TypeId);
                $('#Color').val(data.Color);
                $('#Name').val(data.Name);
                $('#NameBen').val(data.NameBen);
                $('#Height').val(data.Height);
                $('#Width').val(data.Width);
                $('#Length').val(data.Length);
                $('#Price').val(data.Price);
                $('#Description').val(data.Description);
                $('#DescriptionBen').val(data.DescriptionBen);
                document.getElementById('IsPublished').checked = data.IsPublished;
            }
        },
        error:function()
        {

        }

    });
}
```

But it show error "An error occurred while processing your request".
i analysis a lot and i found it. If i get 500 rows then it works fine but when data rows is greater than 500 rows then it show error. Please some one help me. How can i get large number of data by Json.

Comment: Check  `MaxJsonLength` property of the serializer.

Comment: Are you trying to load a chunk of 500+ json items at once or is the root problem displaying 500 rows in a table on the WebUI ?

Comment: is it showing out of memory exception ?
OR
maxJSONLength string property exceptoin ?

Comment: you can refer this link may be it's useful for you:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269438/streaming-large-list-of-data-as-json-format-using-json-net

Comment: type: "GET",
                dataType: "JSON", in you ajax code

Comment: Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23451249/1504480) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7207539/1504480)