# Sending a string in XMLHttpRequest.send('stringJSON') is cutting off the length of my json and so making the json invalid

Tags: javascript, json, server, xmlhttprequest, send

I am trying to send a JSON to my server using the code below. It connects fine, no problems. However, the JSON is invalid when attempted to be parsed. This appears to be because the send() function is cutting the string half way through for no apparent reason. I have searched most of the evening but haven't been able to find a answer to this. If somebody knows why this may be occurring that would be really helpful. My code is as follows:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("PUT", "my-url", false);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xmlHttp.send(jsonString);
    xmlHttp.response;
```

I know this code works as I use it to send smaller JSONs. But when the JSON gets too long it cuts it off.

Comment: There is no inherent limit over how much you can send using JSON. If there is such a limitation to your call, most likely it is set by the server parsing the request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON data size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451217/json-data-size-limit)

Comment: No there server works fine with similar length JSONs from postman. So there is not problem on that end. It may be worth mentioning that the above code is called using the eval function as I am calling it from a C++ exported program that has access to a javascript singleton via .eval(). I haven't had any problems like this before though.